# how do i sort files listed by php

Tags: php, sorting

im a little confused how i can sort my results. Im returning a list of files in a directory and need them to be sorted in some way...

```
// Start directory
getDirectory('../gallery/photos');

function getDirectory( $path = '.', $level = 0 ){

 // Directories to ignore when listing output. 
 $ignore = array( '.', '..' ); 

 // Open the directory to the handle $dh
 $dh = @opendir( $path ); 

 // Loop through the directory 
 while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ) {

  // Change filename to display date
  $displaydate= date('jS M Y', strtotime($file)); 

  // Check that this file is not to be ignored 
  if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) ) { 

   // Indent spacing for better view
   $spaces = str_repeat( '&nbsp;', ( $level * 5 ) );

   // Show directories only
   if(is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){ 

    // Re-call this same function but on a new directory. 
    // this is what makes function recursive. 
    echo "$spaces<a href='$path/$file'>$displaydate</a><br />";
    getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) ); 
   } 
  } 
 }
 // Close the directory handle 
 closedir( $dh ); 
}
```

where would i apply the sort function?

thanks

Comment: Before everyone suggests to use `glob()` now, please read [Bill Karwin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin)'s [Putting Glob To Test](http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/28/putting-glob-to-the-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend scrapping that function and using [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
$files = glob("dir/*");
sort( $files );
```

Comment: glob() should automatically sort the list for you, at least that's the default behaviour

Comment: it does, im not sure what kind of sorting he wants so i jsut showed where the sort would go.

Answer (score 1):

the answer would be adding your entries to an array and sort it

but seriously. your code (i dunno where you got that snipped from) however looks really outdated. there are far more elegant ways to do that.

for example [glob](http://php.net/manual/de/function.glob.php)

just to make your code modified to to essentially do what you want and nothing mroe you may have the following:

```
// Start directory
getDirectory('../gallery/photos');

function getDirectory( $path = '.', $level = 0 ){

 // Directories to ignore when listing output. 
 $ignore = array( '.', '..' ); 

 // Open the directory to the handle $dh
 //$dh = @opendir( $path ); 

 // Loop through the directory 

 //while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ) {
  $files = $files = glob($path.DS."*");
  sort($files);
  foreach($files as file) {
  // Change filename to display date
  $displaydate= date('jS M Y', strtotime($file)); 

  // Check that this file is not to be ignored 
  if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) ) { 

   // Indent spacing for better view
   $spaces = str_repeat( '&nbsp;', ( $level * 5 ) );

   // Show directories only
   if(is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){ 

    // Re-call this same function but on a new directory. 
    // this is what makes function recursive. 
    echo "$spaces<a href='$path/$file'>$displaydate</a><br />";
    getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) ); 
   } 
  } 
 }
 // Close the directory handle 
 closedir( $dh ); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help joe, im having some trouble getting this to work: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in J:\xampp\htdocs\bunker\test\gallery.php on line 33.... line 33 being - foreach($files as file) {

Answer (score 0):

You would need to accumulate the results of each iteration, instead of echoing them to the user. Then, after the function has finished recursing, it should sort the results. Only sort the results when `$level` is 1, though. If you don't, it will sort the results after every recursion.