# sort files by their name in php

Tags: php, filesort, file-listing

How can I sort files inside a directory by their file name using PHP ? I have many files inside a directory and I have to list them sorted by name in a page.

Comment: Try this answer [how do i sort files listed by php](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4180308/751619)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i sort files listed by php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180282/how-do-i-sort-files-listed-by-php)

Answer (score 1):

Store `filenames` into an array and [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) it.

Answer (score 0):

store files inside array and sort by file name or use scandir() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php